# Interactive row of a ListView created with a data model

Tags: android, listview, model, adapter, interactive

I have been following [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive) tutorial and everything was going nice and easy until I decided to implement some stuff on my own.
I have the following adapter:

```
package alphabet.fast.scroll;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class interactiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<model> {

    private final List<model> list;
    private final Activity context;

    public interactiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<model> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_row, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected ImageView avatar;
        protected TextView name;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.avatar = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
            viewHolder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    model element = (model) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
                    element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                }
            });
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.avatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon2);
        holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        return view;
    }
}
```

this model:

```
package alphabet.fast.scroll;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class model {

    private Drawable avatar;
    private String name;
    private boolean selected;

    public model(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        selected = false;
    }

    public model(String name, Drawable avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar; 
        this.name = name;
        selected = false;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

and MainActivity :

```
package alphabet.fast.scroll;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class tutorial extends ListActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        ArrayAdapter<model> adapter = new interactiveArrayAdapter(this, getModel());
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

        private List<model> getModel() {
            List<model> list = new ArrayList<model>();
            list.add(get("Linux"));
            list.add(get("Windows7"));
            list.add(get("Android"));
            list.add(get("iPhone"));
            list.add(get2("Problem coming up here", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)));
            return list;
        }

        private model get(String s) {
            return new model(s);
        }

        private model get2(String s, Drawable av) {
            return new model(s, av);
        }
}
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code and why my constructor with text and drawable is not working properly - I don't get an updated `avatar` for the `Problem coming up here` row in the ListView ?

Comment: whats the result that you see?

Comment: The result is the default view as in the custom_row.xml I have already defined.

Comment: where is the code where you are setting the "avatar image from your pojo" to imageView. I can see you are setting "icon2" from drawbles in the code to that image view

Comment: Isn't the constructor 
`public model(String name, Drawable avatar) {
 this.avatar = avatar; 
 this.name = name;
 selected = false;
}` doing this for me?
If this is not the case how could I achieve this?

Comment: got my mistake, there was no getAvatar function... will post my own answer. Thanks for the point-out :)

Comment: happy to help, I have added the same, accept it if helps you. :)

Comment: are you expecting any magic to happen ??  you need to set it at your own . so in`getView()`  replace holder.avatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon2); by your resource . you can find it by list.get(position).getAvatar . (create getter if needed)

Comment: As a side note, you might want to not use lower case names for classes. Just saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of updateing the imageView with the avatar image you are doing
   *`holder.avatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon2);`* 
Rather you should make a method in the Avatar class like 
*`public Drwable getAvatarImage(){
 return this.avatar;
} 

Then you should do as below in your getView method:` 
 holder.avatar.setImageResource(list.get(position).getAvatarImage);*

Comment: Thanks mate, just realized that!